# is it possible to use Spring MVC Test directly in grails, and how?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, spring-mvc-test, spring-restdocs

We think the `Spring Rest Doc` is great for documenting rest api. But it is based on `Spring MVC Test`，and we can't figure out how to use `Spring MVC Test` in my grails apps(Grails 3.0.5).

I tried to use a config class (with `@Configuration` and`@ComponentScan`) to scan grails components into the test context, but it seems like nothing had been loaded (when performing a http request to the `mockmvc`, it got 404).

I also tried to configure the grails controller directly, and got a run time error.

> Could not autowire field: private reactor.bus.EventBus

I also tried to add `@Integration` (from grails) on the test class but recieved the same error.

Please help.

Here are some code samples.
what i tried was adding config class or class locations or grails controller to ContextConfiguration of the test class below. And the test class itself is basically following `spring rest doc` reference.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
//TODO how to scan Grails components into the test context
public class QuestionRestSpec {
@Rule
public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("build/generated-snippets");
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
            .build();
}
}
```

The config class(which has no use):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class AskConfig {
}
```

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: i am using Grails 3.0.5

Comment: Grails 3 is just a Spring Boot app, so, in theory at least, it should be possible although perhaps not really the Grails way. `@Integration` and injecting the `ApplicationContext` using `@Autowired` would be what I'd try. Can you share your attempt at that which didn't work?

Comment: I am not quite sure what do u mean by **@Integration and  injecting the ApplicationContext using @Autowired.** i updated the question by adding some code samples. Basically, it is following the `spring rest doc` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be possible to use MockMvc with Grails. Calls to `MockMvc.perform` fail:

```
HandlerMapping requires a Grails web request. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HandlerMapping requires a Grails web request
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(UrlMappingsHandlerMapping.groovy:113) ~[grails-web-url-mappings-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1120) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.getHandler(TestDispatcherServlet.java:90) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:144) [spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    …
```

[Spring REST Docs 1.1 will hopefully add support for REST Assured](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/102). This removes the need for MockMvc and, instead, will allow the API to be documented by making HTTP calls to a running server in a functional test.

For reference, here's the Spock specification that I used:

```
package com.example.notes

import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
class ApiDocumentationSpec extends Specification {

    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("build/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context

    MockMvc mockMvc

    def setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).build();
    }

    def cleanup() {

    }

    void "list notes"() {
        when:
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/notes")).andReturn()
        then:
            result.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("notes-list-example"));
    }
}
```